# curl cross origin request needs user-agent to work?

Tags: php, curl, request, cors

I am experiencing troubles while trying to query my Cross Domain API.

Here is a simple example of what is happening :

```
curl -i -X POST https://example.com/api/v1/log/create -d 'value=fesfse' -d 'type=3'

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Thu, 15 Jun 2017 15:07:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 219
Set-Cookie: SERVERID31396=234083; path=/; max-age=900
Server: Apache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-IPLB-Instance: 9386

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /api/v1/log/create
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

But the very same request, adding User-Agent, is working (whatever the value is) !

```
curl -i -X POST https://example.com/api/v1/log/create -d 'value=fesfse' -d 'type=3' -H 'User-Agent: toto'

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 15 Jun 2017 15:09:27 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Set-Cookie: SERVERID31396=234083; path=/; max-age=900
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.15
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 58
Access-Control-Max-Age: 0
X-IPLB-Instance: 9387

{"status_code":200,"message":null,"data":null}
```

It's a shared hosting server on ovh.com, running php 7.0.15 on Apache 2.
Can anyone explains that behaviour ?

Comment: Curl has a built-in user agent string like `User-Agent: curl/7.51.0` that it uses if you don'y specify one. It's not uncommon to find servers that reject requests from it.

Comment: @AlexHowansky You should put this as a answer because it seems that it's exactly what's happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curl has a built-in user agent string like `User-Agent: curl/7.51.0` that it uses if you don'y specify one. It's not uncommon to find servers that reject requests from it. (Which is silly, because it's trivially easy to fake.) If the host is being picky like this, you can just provide a [user agent string from a real browser](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Chrome) to fool the host.

Answer (score 1):

Code on the server you are making the request to looks at the User-Agent header and rejects some requests. Presumably on the basis that they are not browsers or bots that it trusts.